# Setting SelectedListItem property Selected to false isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-select, selectlistitem, select-options

i have a model called QA in this model I have a foreign key SectionId. when creating a QA the SectionId gets and Id of a Section called "Unclassified" as shown

```
         public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateQAViewModel qA)
    {
 var qa = mapper.Map<QA>(qA);
 qa.SectionId = UnclassifiedIds.UnClassifiedSectionId;
 qa.CaseNumber = Randomizer.GetAUniqueString(qaS.Select(q => q.CaseNumber).ToList(), 
 (int)Num(qa), true);
    // code
```

after the QA is registered an admin answers the Question and moves the QA to the right section so I created a service that gives an IEnumerable< SelectListItem > as shown

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>> GetSectionsIdAsync()
    {
        var SectionsLists = await uoW.SectionsRepository.GetAllSectionsAsync();

        return SectionsLists.Select(vl => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = vl.Title.ToString(),
            Value = vl.Id.ToString(),
        Selected = false

        }).Distinct();
    }
```

i injected this service to the view as shown:

```
@inject ISelectServices service

    <div class="form-control">
        <select asp-for="SectionId" asp-items="@await service.GetSectionsIdAsync()" class="form-select">

            <option selected="selected" value="">
                please choose a section
            </option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="SectionId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

The option I want to be shown to the user is the " please choose a section" but it keeps showing "Unclassified" cuz it's the current value of the item (qa).
as shown above I already set the property selected to false in the SelectListItems and used the attribute selected="selected" in the view but it still shows "Unclassifed".
How can I make it always show the option please choose a section?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an empty value to `SectionsLists`

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>> GetSectionsIdAsync()
{
    var SectionsLists = await uoW.SectionsRepository.GetAllSectionsAsync();

    var retval = SectionsLists.Select(vl => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = vl.Title.ToString(),
        Value = vl.Id.ToString(),
        Selected = false
    }).Distinct();

    retval.Insert(0, new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "please choose a section",
        Value = string.Empty
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: I tried that as well it didn't work. the option is being added to the dropdown but the selected item is always "Unclassified" whose id is the current value to SectionId of the current item.